# Find $\alpha$ such that the given point is critical for a implicitly defined funtion.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, solution-verification, implicit-function-theorem

Can anyone check my solution for this exercise?

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by $F(x,y,z) = \alpha xz + x\arctan(z) + z\sin(2x+y) -1.$
>
> Prove that a function $z=f(x,y)$ can be defined around $(0, \pi/2,1)$ and find $\alpha$ such that $(0, \pi/2)$ is a critical point of $f$.

To show that $z=f(x,y)$ can be defined around $(0,\pi/2,1)$ I should apply the implicit function theorem, this is, I should check that $F(0,\pi/2,1)=0$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(0,\pi/2,1) \neq .0$

I have $F(0,\pi/2,1) = \alpha(0)(1) + (0)\arctan(1) + (1)\sin(\pi/2) -1 = 0$; and also $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = \alpha x + \displaystyle\frac{x}{1+z^2}+\sin(2x+y)$ which means that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(0,\pi/2,1) = \sin(\pi/2) = 1 \neq 0$. Then by the implicit function theorem a function $z=f(x,y)$ can be defined.

Now to find $\alpha$ such that $(0,\pi/2)$ is a critical point, this means that must be $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$.

Considering that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \alpha z + \arctan z + 2z\cos(2x+y), \displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = z\cos(2x+y)$ and

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \displaystyle\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} (x,y,f(x,y))}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(x,y,f(x,y))}$, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \displaystyle\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} (x,y,f(x,y))}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(x,y,f(x,y))}$.

If $(x,y) = (0,\pi/2)$ then $F(x,y,z) = 0$ implies that $z=1$. Also $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,\pi/2,1) = \alpha + \arctan(1), \displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,\pi/2,1) = 0$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(0,\pi/2,1) = 1$ .

Thus, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \alpha + \arctan(1) \implies \alpha = -1$

Am I missing something?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning looks pretty good to me. Do you have a reason for believing it might be wrong?

Comment: The only question asked was "Am I missing something?" I could have said just "No," but admitting the possibility of my being wrong, I merely said that I believed the answer was "no." Was there something else I was suppose to day?

Comment: Sorry, the second sentence makes it look like you're asking for clarification, but in the proper context I agree this is as good an answer as the OP can expect, given there doesn't seem to be any mistake.

Comment: I don't have a reason to believe there was a mistake, but I also believed having the right answer before even if I didn't. I just wanted someone to check it because someone else may see something that I didn't (it happens more often that you could think!). And looking back to what I did, I'm not sure why a few hours ago I conclude that $\alpha=−1$, shouldn't be $\alpha=−\pi/4$?

Comment: Ooops. Yes, @Dante, you're right -- that last step went off the rails. Everything else looked so right that I was lulled into a false sense of complacency. Apologies for not spotting that. (And I now feel justified in my hesitance in confidently stating it was correct!)